# 'numpy.float64' object is not callable while extracting audios features

Tags: python, numpy, audio, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I am trying to extract some features in audio files and i have this error : ''numpy.float64' object is not callable'. I have seen this come up in other questions but others answers were in specific context and i don't really undestand what that means!

first i use this code to create functions to extracte my features:

```
def melCoef (audio_path):
    y,sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc = 13)

    return np.mean(mfccs)
     def linearCoef (audio_path):
    y,sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
    lpc = librosa.core.lpc(y,16)
    return np.mean(lpc)

def gramCoef(audio_path):
    fs, sig = scipy.io.wavfile.read(audio_path)
    gram = gfcc(sig, fs=fs, num_ceps=13)
    return np.mean(gram)



def crossRate(audio_path):
    y,sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
    zcr = librosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(y)
    return np.mean(zcr)

def energy(audio_path):
    y,sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
    value = np.sum(y ** 2) / np.float64(len(y))
    return value

def duration(audio_path):
    y,sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
    duree = librosa.get_duration(y=y, sr=sr)
    return duree

def haut (audio_path):
    sound = parselmouth.Sound(audio_path)
    pitch = call(sound, "To Pitch", 0.0, 75, 600)
    mean_pitch = call(pitch, "Get mean", 0, 0, "Hertz")
    return mean_pitch

def noiseRatio (audio_path):
    sound = parselmouth.Sound(audio_path)
    harmonicity = call(sound, "To Harmonicity (cc)", 0.01, 75, 0.1, 1.0)
    HNR = call(harmonicity, "Get mean", 0, 0)
    return HNR

def jiter(audio_path):
    sound = parselmouth.Sound(audio_path)
    pointProcess = call(sound, "To PointProcess (periodic, cc)", 75, 500)
    localJitter = call(pointProcess, "Get jitter (local)", 0, 0, 0.0001, 0.02, 1.3)
    return localJitter

def abJiter(audio_path):
    sound = parselmouth.Sound(audio_path)
    pointProcess = call(sound, "To PointProcess (periodic, cc)", 75, 500)
    localabsoluteJitter = call(pointProcess, "Get jitter (local, absolute)", 0, 0, 0.0001, 0.02, 1.3)
    return localabsoluteJitter

def shimmer(audio_path):
    sound = parselmouth.Sound(audio_path)
    pointProcess = call(sound, "To PointProcess (periodic, cc)", 75, 500)
    localShimmer =  call([sound, pointProcess], "Get shimmer (local)", 0, 0, 0.0001, 0.02, 1.3, 1.6)
    return localShimmer

def abShimmer(audio_path):
    sound = parselmouth.Sound(audio_path)
    pointProcess = call(sound, "To PointProcess (periodic, cc)", 75, 500)
    localdbShimmer = call([sound, pointProcess], "Get shimmer (local_dB)", 0, 0, 0.0001, 0.02, 1.3, 1.6)
    return localdbShimmer
```

and after i use these function to extract features on all the audio files like this:

```
features = []
folder = 'audio_classés'
for audio_file in array[:,0]:
    if audio_file.endswith('.wav'):
        mfcc = melCoef(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        gfcc= gramCoef(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        lpc= linearCoef(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        zcr= crossRate(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        value= energy(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        duree= duration(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        pitch= haut(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        hnr= noiseRatio(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        jitter= jiter(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        abjiter = abJiter(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        shimmer= shimmer(folder+'/'+audio_file)
        abshimmer= abShimmer(folder+'/'+audio_file)


        global_feature = np.hstack([mfcc,gfcc,lpc,zcr,energy,duration,pitch,hnr,jitter,abjiter,shimmer,
                                    abshimmer])

        features.append(global_feature)
```

but i have this error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-aafa6e12e769> in <module>
      4     if audio_file.endswith('.wav'):
      5         mfcc = melCoef(folder+'/'+audio_file)
----> 6         gfcc= gramCoef(folder+'/'+audio_file)
      7         lpc= linearCoef(folder+'/'+audio_file)
      8         zcr= crossRate(folder+'/'+audio_file)

<ipython-input-5-dfd5660f29c4> in gramCoef(audio_path)
     12 def gramCoef(audio_path):
     13     fs, sig = scipy.io.wavfile.read(audio_path)
---> 14     gram = gfcc(sig, fs=fs, num_ceps=13)
     15     return np.mean(gram)
     16 

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

I don't undestand , can you help me please?

Comment: What is `gfcc` ? You have it defined here `gfcc= gramCoef(folder+'/'+audio_file)` as an output of a function which returns a number, and then you call it inside that very function as a method.

Comment: yes I define gfcc as the output of my gramCoef function, this is what I do recover, do you think that the error is due to the fact that the method in the function has the same name? I'm going to modify that then for all my functions

Comment: I changed it but i have the same error!

Comment: Can you post the full relevant code, please.

Comment: thank you , now it is work , i remplace all the name of my variable and i dont have this error